# How do I switch off SCHEMABINDING for a view without recreating it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

How do I switch off `SCHEMABINDING` for a view without recreating it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. It's good that you use SCHEMABINDING (we do always) and sometimes you have to remove it to change a dependent object. Just [ALTER the view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846.aspx)

```
ALTER VIEW myView
--Remove this WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ...
GO
```

Comment: so did I, but sometimes other objects (functions, views) depend on this one. So it will be good to mark /unmark this flag for a time :). So it is impossible in the current version of db, yes?

Comment: @garik: correct, I have the same problem. Run ALTER on each dependent object... At any point in time SQL Server will enforce the rules: you can't "switch off" because this would lead to inconsistency

Answer (score 14):

After looking around for hours, I created 2 stored proc for this.
Hope this helps someone

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ViewRemoveSchemaBinding
    @ViewName VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PositionShemaBinding INT
    DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @Command = OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(@ViewName));
    SET @PositionShemaBinding = CHARINDEX('WITH SCHEMABINDING', @Command)

    IF NOT @PositionShemaBinding = 0 BEGIN
        -- WITH SCHEMA BINDING IS PRESENT... Let's remove it !
        SET @Command = STUFF(@Command, CHARINDEX('WITH SCHEMABINDING', @Command), LEN('WITH SCHEMABINDING'), '');
        SET @Command = REPLACE(@Command, 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW');

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Command
    END
END
```

And to put the SCHEMABINDING :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ViewAddSchemaBinding
    @ViewName VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PositionShemaBinding INT
    DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ObjectName VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT  @Command = OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(@ViewName)),
            @ObjectName = OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@ViewName));

    SET @PositionShemaBinding = PATINDEX('%WITH SCHEMABINDING%', @Command)

    IF @PositionShemaBinding = 0 BEGIN
        -- WITH SCHEMA BINDING IS NOT PRESENT... Let's add it !
        SET @Command = REPLACE(@Command, 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW');

        -- IF OBJECT NAME IS INTO BRAKETS, We need to handle it
       IF NOT CHARINDEX('[' + @ObjectName + ']', @Command) = 0 BEGIN
           SET @ObjectName = '[' + @ObjectName + ']'
       END

       SET @Command = STUFF(@Command, CHARINDEX(@ObjectName, @Command), LEN(@ObjectName), @ObjectName + ' WITH SCHEMABINDING ');

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Command
    END
END
```

It is provided "as is"...

Answer (score 10):

Won't ALTER VIEW allow for you to get this done? When you create a view you would do:

```
CREATE VIEW
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT stmt
GO
```

so, lose the WITH clause:

```
ALTER VIEW viewname
AS
SELECT stmt
GO
```

See [ALTER VIEW on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846.aspx)

Comment: _"Won't ALTER VIEW allow for you to get this done?"_ - it requires you to re-supply the definition of the `VIEW` which is a big hassle - ideally we'd be able to run _just_ `ALTER VIEW WITH ( SCHEMABINDING = ON|OFF );` without re-supplying the `SELECT...` part.

Answer (score 3):

This version of ViewRemoveSchemaBinding works even if the view has been renamed since it was created. (The problem is that if the view has been renamed, OBJECT_DEFINITION() will still return a definition using the old name.)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ViewRemoveSchemaBinding]
    @ViewName VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PositionShemaBinding INT
    DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @Command = OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(@ViewName));
    SET @PositionShemaBinding = CHARINDEX('WITH SCHEMABINDING', @Command)

    IF NOT @PositionShemaBinding = 0 BEGIN
        SET @Command = 'ALTER VIEW ' + @ViewName + ' ' + RIGHT(@Command, LEN(@Command) - @PositionShemaBinding + 1);

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Command
    END
END
```

It seems that after running this the renaming issue goes away, and so ViewAddSchemaBinding doesn't need to be altered....

Comment: This doesn't work, as the command still contains 'WITH SCHEMABINDING' - to fix it, change the usage of `RIGHT` to: `RIGHT(@Command, LEN(@Command) - (@PositionShemaBinding + LEN('WITH SCHEMABINDING')))`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like..

```
@Command = REPLACE(@Command,'WITH SCHEMABINDING','-- WITH SCHEMABINDING')
```

This would allow you to scan the `--WITH SCHEMABINDING` to reinstate the schemabinding after the object was altered.